# Find And Delete

Tags: command-line, files, rm

I want to find and delete first 10 largest files. Below is the command to find out 10 largest files.

```
du -a * | sort -n -r | head -n 10
```

Comment: This does not exclude directories and it is a really awfully bad idea to delete files blindly like that.  You should make it list the target files and review it.

Comment: Assume that i'm in a folder that contains only files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the GNU implementation of all utilities below:

```
find /some/folder -type f -printf '%s\t%p\0' | \
    sort -rnz | \
    head -10 -z | \
    cut -f2- -z | \
    xargs -0 rm -f
```

Comment: thanks @Sato , can you please mention the description of this command ?

Comment: @rlinux57:  In **summary**, `find` will search for files (not directories) and `sort` them by size in reverse order, then `head` will extract the first 10, `cut` will retrieve the file name and `xargs` will pass those to `rm`.  Check the commands' man pages for more details.

Answer (score -1):

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort | tail -n 1
```

This only deletes the files, and not directories.

All you needed was this.

- xargs rm -> Delete the file.

Also the maxdepth can be increased to also allow deleting files from sub-directories .

Comment: This sorts files by name rather than size.